# choosing development framework for game

Tags: frameworks, cocos2d-x, game-engine

I used to be a as3 game programmer. when I begin develop game, I would use a coding framework(suppose these called coding framework) like puremvc/mate/robotlegs plus other graphic framework like starling/away3d/featherUI. And now I am a C++ game programmer(novice), and I want to make a game using cocos2dx. But cocos2dx just a graphics framework, and I want to choose a coding framework like puremvc. I know puremvc has a c++ multicore version, but I found it very hard to learn because there no docs no example on the internet, I would not use puremvc-cpp until I found a good example or document.

I wonder to know that if other people that developing game with cocos2dx did not use any other framework? if yes, then what's mainstream framework for this situation. If no, then I am very sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answer is late, but I'd like to suggest you a possible scenario: if you're learning to be a C++ programmer, then you'll surely find an easy path to move to the Unreal Engine to create your games.

About the chance to use the PureMVC implementation (standard or multicore), make sure to subdivide your game into 5 tiers:

- ViewTech (Unreal, engine logic)
- View (PureMVC Mediators, visual logic)
- Controller (PureMVC Commands, game logic)
- Model (PureMVC Proxies, entities logic)
- DBTech (LightSpeed is my suggestion here, persistent logic)

PureMVC is feature frozen, so you can pick up any of the skeletal C++ examples from its main site and adapt them to suit your needs. So even if there are not much working examples out there, you'll still be able to build a prototype in less than 2 days.

This solution doesn't use Cocos2dx, but I think you'll have far more expressive power with these guidelines.

Hope this helps. Bye!

Comment: extreme nice answer!, thanks Francesco Bulleri! good luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

You won't need any extra frameworks when using cocos2d-x.

Cocos2d-x isn't just a graphics library - it's a whole graphics, input and audio framework. The framework itself promotes a certain type of architecture, so a coding framework like the ones you mentioned would probably not fit too well.

I suggest you have a look at the official samples ([github](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-samples)) and use them as guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript to build your game, you might try the PureMVC JS port: http://js.puremvc.org

Essentially, PureMVC just want's to help you keep your model, view, and controller concerns separated, and it does so just the same in JS as it did in the AS3 world.